# How to enter captions for multiple file uploads

Tags: php, image-uploading, caption

I have a photo gallery that it is divided as photo albums and each photo album has number of photos under it.  I have no problems uploading multiple files, what I am missing is the technique to get the user to enter the caption.

I have got some techniques in mind that I want somebody to help me to choose one of them if they are right or if there is a better one to tell me about it.

1. Uploading the pictures and then let them enter the caption one by one.
2. Just cancel the idea of uploading multiple files and get them to enter the photos one by one.

Comment: Is the issue forcing a caption with each image?

Comment: the issue is the idea of how to make it possible for the user to enter a caption for each image not forcing it and sorry, i am not for an english speaking country, like you get to the file field and click on browse and then you select your files how i am able to get them to enter the caption

Comment: I'd go with your first thought and upload the pics and then do a layout that provides room for captions. That sounds pretty straight forward.

Comment: My approach would have been, I'l create a table for captions in database. And against each pic, there would be a caption field. Now on the event of Image uplod submit button, I'l insert the captions with a loop.

Comment: thanks alot everybody i will go for the first approach then, and sorry for bothering anybody.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you serve my answer,
Okay, I've managed to get it working, or at least it's how I wanted it to work. Here's my new modification.

Here is my `uploading.js` file

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
        var fileList = new Array();
        $("#droparea").bind('dragenter dragover', false).bind('drop', function(e){

            $.each(e.dataTransfer.files, function(index, file){
                fileList.push(file);
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                fileReader.onload = (function(e){

                    var form = document.createElement('form');
                    form.action = 'uploads';
                    form.className = 'forms';

                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = e.target.result;
                    img.width = 80;

                    var label = document.createElement('label');
                    $(label).append('Image Caption');

                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.type = "text";
                    input.name = "title";
                    input.value = "";

                    var button = document.createElement('button');
                    $(button).append('Upload');
                    $(form).append(img);    
                    $(form).append(input);              
                    $(form).append(button);             

                    $('#uploads').append(form);
                });
            });

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

        });

        $('#upload-all').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();     
          var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);    
          $('form').each(function(i){
           var title = $(this).find('input').val();
           formData.append('file[]', fileList[i]);
           formData.append('title[]', title);
        }); 

       upload(formData);
});

function upload(data) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post', 'upload.php', true);
    xhr.send(data);

}

        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //var index what does this do?
            var index = $(this).index();
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            formData.append('file', fileList[index]);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('post', 'upload.php', true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    });
```

My upload template file is `.html`

```
<div id="droparea" class="droparea">
    Drop files here to upload
</div>
<div id="uploads">

</div>
<button id="upload-all">Upload All</button>
```